# bcp.exe does not copy rows but there is no error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sqlbulkcopy, bcp

I am new to bcp which i am trying to figure out. I have table in sql server

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SL_REQUEST_ID
(
    requestId numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT X_requestId
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (requestId)
)
```

I am running follwing from command prompt

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\bcp"
>   BCP_Experiment_DB.dbo.SL_REQUEST_ID in
>   M:\BCP_Experiment\SL_REQUEST_ID_FileData -S BCP_Experiment_Serve
>   r -T

My Datafile is shown in below image.

[image]

When we run above command on commnd propmt following process happens

```
Enter the file storage type of field requestId [numeric]:
Enter prefix-length of field requestId [1]:
Enter field terminator [none]:

Do you want to save this format information in a file? [Y/n] n

Starting copy...

0 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1
```

Why that one record is not getting copied?

I am not sure this matters but for info my sql server BCP_Experiment_Server is a sql 2005 instance.

Comment: Do you use a format file? Please post that.

Comment: no I do not use format file

Comment: I do not think it matters still though will metion file SL_REQUEST_ID_FileData is being created by bcp out form Syabse ASE